# Why don't CSS radial gradients work in Edge?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, radial-gradients

I got the following solution for diagonal scanlines from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434196/1191147) to my previous question:

```
html {
  height:100%;
  background:
    radial-gradient(#000 0.5px,transparent 0.5px) 0   0   /3px 3px,
    radial-gradient(#000 0.5px,transparent 0.5px) 1px 1px /3px 3px,
    radial-gradient(#000 0.5px,transparent 0.5px) 2px 2px /3px 3px,
    url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/800/800.jpg) center/cover;
}
```

The solution works perfectly to reproduce the desired effect in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't make any difference in Edge. This doesn't seem to make any sense as [all versions of Edge](https://caniuse.com/#search=gradients) support gradients.

Why is Edge not reproducing these gradients?

Comment: it doesn't like float number, if you replace 0.5 by 1 it will work but of course the result will be off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another version with `conic-gradient()` that should work on the last version of Edge according to: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-conic-gradients

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  /* fallback for firefox */
  background:
    radial-gradient(#000 0.5px,transparent 0.5px) 0   0   /3px 3px,
    radial-gradient(#000 0.5px,transparent 0.5px) 1px 1px /3px 3px,
    radial-gradient(#000 0.5px,transparent 0.5px) 2px 2px /3px 3px,
    url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/800/800.jpg) center/cover;
  /**/
  background:
    conic-gradient(from -90deg at 1px 1px,#000 0 90deg,transparent 0) 0   0  /3px 3px,
    conic-gradient(from -90deg at 1px 1px,#000 0 90deg,transparent 0) 1px 1px/3px 3px,
    conic-gradient(from -90deg at 1px 1px,#000 0 90deg,transparent 0) 2px 2px/3px 3px,
    url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/800/800.jpg) center/cover;
}
```

You can also consider a small SVG as background and it will work fine everywhere:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 3 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="1" height="1" /></svg>') 0   0  /3px 3px,
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 3 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="1" height="1" /></svg>') 1px 1px/3px 3px,
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 3 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="1" height="1" /></svg>') 2px 2px/3px 3px,
    url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/800/800.jpg) center/cover;
}
```

Comment: My bad, I assumed that I had the latest version of Edge being on Windows 10 but  apparently it's now a standalone product that needs to be installed. I can confirm the conic-gradient solution works on Edge as well as Firefox and Chrome, although that still leaves all the other (more common) versions of Edge, so the SVG solution is still superior.